# What's the quickest or easiest way to create a new table based on data from multiple columns?

Tags: excel

My apologies for the somewhat vague question title. An example will probably help illustrate what I'm trying to accomplish. What's the easiest way to turn a table that looks like this:

```
CUSTOMER    ZIP      EMAIL 1        EMAIL 2         EMAIL 3
________________________________________________________________
Mike        33309    mike@me.com                    mark@me.com
Bob         53023                   bob@wow.com
Jen         66012                   jen@go.com      julie@go.com
```

Into a table that looks like this:

```
EMAIL             CUSTOMER    ZIP
______________________________________
mike@me.com       Mike        33309
mark@me.com       Mike        33309
bob@wow.com       Bob         53023
jen@go.com        Jen         66012
julie@go.com      Jen         66012
```

Multiple columns are identified (in this case, multiple columns containing emails) and are moved around so that all of the other columns match. I really wish I could explain this better, so hopefully the tables above are enough.

Hoping there is a nice and simple built-in method of Excel that will do this. If not, I am proficient enough in VBA to adapt some code.

Comment: Is this a one time affair, or something you'd have to do over and over again?

Comment: This is something I probably need to do on a weekly basis. And it can range anywhere from 10 or 20 rows to a thousand.

Comment: It's fairly simple to get close to that with a few formulas (1 per column...) but you'd be left with empty rows where there's no email. filtering that is very simple, but if you do it over and over again, maybe you'd prefer a VBA solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you choose to take care of this VBA-way, here's an example of code you could write. In my example, I have data in `Sheet1` and it is active. I have an empty `Sheet2`.

```
Option Explicit

Sub Test()

    Dim CurrentRowNumber As Integer
    CurrentRowNumber = 2

    Dim FinalSheetRowNumber As Integer
    FinalSheetRowNumber = 2

    Do
        If Len(Trim(Range("A" & CurrentRowNumber).Text)) = 0 Then
            Exit Do
        End If

        ' if all emails are blank, copy values in A and B columns
        If Len(Trim(Range("C" & CurrentRowNumber).Text)) = 0 And _
            Len(Trim(Range("D" & CurrentRowNumber).Text)) = 0 And _
            Len(Trim(Range("E" & CurrentRowNumber).Text)) = 0 Then

            ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A" & FinalSheetRowNumber).Value = Range("A" & CurrentRowNumber).Text
            ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2").Range("B" & FinalSheetRowNumber).Value = Range("B" & CurrentRowNumber).Text
            ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2").Range("B" & FinalSheetRowNumber).Value = " "
            FinalSheetRowNumber = FinalSheetRowNumber + 1
        End If

        ' if C is not blank, copy the row with C
        If Len(Trim(Range("C" & CurrentRowNumber).Text)) > 0 Then
            ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A" & FinalSheetRowNumber).Value = Range("A" & CurrentRowNumber).Text
            ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2").Range("B" & FinalSheetRowNumber).Value = Range("B" & CurrentRowNumber).Text
            ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2").Range("C" & FinalSheetRowNumber).Value = Range("C" & CurrentRowNumber).Text
            FinalSheetRowNumber = FinalSheetRowNumber + 1
        End If

        ' if D is not blank, copy the row with D
        If Len(Trim(Range("D" & CurrentRowNumber).Text)) > 0 Then
            ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A" & FinalSheetRowNumber).Value = Range("A" & CurrentRowNumber).Text
            ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2").Range("B" & FinalSheetRowNumber).Value = Range("B" & CurrentRowNumber).Text
            ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2").Range("C" & FinalSheetRowNumber).Value = Range("D" & CurrentRowNumber).Text
            FinalSheetRowNumber = FinalSheetRowNumber + 1
        End If

        ' if E is not blank, copy the row with E
        If Len(Trim(Range("E" & CurrentRowNumber).Text)) > 0 Then
            ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A" & FinalSheetRowNumber).Value = Range("A" & CurrentRowNumber).Text
            ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2").Range("B" & FinalSheetRowNumber).Value = Range("B" & CurrentRowNumber).Text
            ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2").Range("C" & FinalSheetRowNumber).Value = Range("E" & CurrentRowNumber).Text
            FinalSheetRowNumber = FinalSheetRowNumber + 1
        End If

        CurrentRowNumber = CurrentRowNumber + 1
    Loop


End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Suppose your table is located at A1, Row 1 being header row, data starts at Row 2.

You could use an `OFFSET()` function to get the Name & ZIP replicated exactly 3 times per source row:

```
=OFFSET(A$1,1+(ROW()-1)/3,0)
```

That gets the Name replicated. The "1" in the `ROW()-1` is the first row where you locate the output table. You do the same, but replace `A$1` with `B$1` for the ZIP.

As for the emails, it's quite similar:

```
=OFFSET(C$1,1+(ROW()-1)/3,MOD(ROW()-1,3))
```

Here the row is calculated as before, but we're also circling the columns.

In the end you'll get a table close to what you wanted but you'll have the email column set to 0 where no data exists. That's easy to filter out with auto-filter or whatever you choose.